# clang++ default parameters or configuration file

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

I would like to develop in C++ 14 and to make that standard a default for my compilers (mainly g++ and clang++).

This has the advantage of avoid messing up with the internal configurations of the Eclipse CDT, for parsing, compiling etc.

For the gcc compiler, I manage to provide a "specs" file and, finally, now C++14 code compiles as simple as:

$g++ testcpp14.cpp

However, I did not find a similar thing for clang(++). It is just like providing some command line parameters by default for the compiler, or a configuration.

Is there any configuration file for clang/clang++? Or for the C++ language that the compiler uses (as clang++ is just a driver).

Thank you very much.

edit: I try to avoid shells, that is providing scripts that later delegate the compilation towards the trye compiler. Reason?: well, you have to provide a lot of scripts (g++, gcc, clang, clang++ etc.) and it still does not prevent an IDE to call /usr/bin/g++ directly, bypassing the PATH-provided script. Only if you replace the binary /usr/bin/g++ (or clang++) you may achieve something, but this is unmaintainable when you upgrade the .deb gcc package.

Comment: I'm not sure I would change the defaults of compilation mode for `g++`, seems like a good recipe to break or alter the compilation of anything you may download (remember that C++14 and C++11 introduce both incompatibilities and semantic differences, i.e. you may have valid C++98 code not compiling or - worse - "silently" exhibiting different behavior when compiled in C++11 or C++14 mode). Explicitly stating the required compiler flags is way safer.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Thank you, I am well aware of that. Either I will update the code, either I will provide corresponding std=gnu++98 flag for that code. The sole thing that I ask is that *by default* the compiler to work as I want (C++14). Is not really much, just changing the default setting. Besides, this will really motivate me to update the code to C++14...

Comment: The problem is not with your code, but with anything else you may download and have to compile - e.g. I happened to compile gcc, MinGW, Qt, wine, ffmpeg and other "complicated" packages all in the last month, and I can assure you that it's rarely easy to plug a compile switch in the right places through their build systems (especially if they have both C++98 and C++11 bits). In general, it's better to avoid messing with the defaults of global system tools, because scripts and the like often make unspoken assumptions about their environment, so the less you move from the defaults, the better.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Yes. But it would be just like I would provide a CXXFLAGS containing c++14. I will overwrite that if really needed. I look forward to what's next and I don't like that the defaults keep me in a old world. On that consideration, I would have stick with Windows (95?) because was the default on my laptop.

Comment: A colleague of mine has always a messed up environment (bizarre symlinks, defaults-changing environment vars, dirty sandboxes, ...) and he's the one who experiences all kind of pains in building almost any nontrivial project (both in-house and external); debugging this kind of issues is just frustration and waste of time, usually yielding no net gain in useful knowledge. I suggest you to avoid this kind of stuff because from my experience the potential pains outweigh the dubious gains. Of course it's just a suggestion, do as you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Clang 6, it supports [configuration files](https://releases.llvm.org/6.0.0/tools/clang/docs/UsersManual.html#configuration-files). Command-line options provided in the file are prepended to the rest of the options on the command line. The file name can be provided on the command line, or can be encoded in the name of the command used to invoke the compiler.

The example use case in the question is unnecessary, though, because another change introduced in Clang 6 was to make the default C++ dialect be C++14 (more precisely, gnu++14).

Comment: Can I add environment variables in the config file? such as `-I $HOME/include`

Comment: I wouldn't expect so, @Liu. Clang would surely interpret that as literally `$HOME`.

Comment: Thanks. I read the website you mentioned. How can I know what `CLANG_CONFIG_FILE_USER_DIR` is if I didn't compile the clang by myself?

Comment: Sounds like a good question to ask on Stack Overflow, @Liu. If I were trying to answer it myself, I might run `strace -f clang --config debug.cfg`. The output should include some `stat` or `open` calls that mention the full paths of the places it looks when trying to open the file.

Comment: Thanks. let me ask directly on Stock Overflow.